# How to prevent reload on Tizen Public Preview Deeplink?

Tags: deep-linking, tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app

I'm writing a web app for Tizen Smart TV. One of the required features is implementing the Smarthub Public Preview deeplinking.
I have setup the app to open at a specific content when the Public preview tile is clicked. However, I cannot prevent the app to reload. The documentation mentions adding the **appcontrol** event to the window event listeners, but I don't think this event is being recognized by the app, since the code is not executed.
It only works if I directly add my deeplink() method to the onload property.

According to documentation, this piece of code should prevent the app to reload, but it is not working:

```
<tizen:app-control>
  <tizen:src name='index.html' reload='disable'></tizen:src>
  <tizen:operation name='http://samsung.com/appcontrol/operation/eden_resume'></tizen:operation> 
</tizen:app-control>
```

window eventListener is not working wither:

```
onload="window.addEventListener('appcontrol', deepLink)"
```

Any help on how to implement this correctly?

Thank you in advance

Comment: We are using the exact same and it is working, You can try removing other properties in config.xml and have only those required for deep link and give it a try.

Comment: Hi, @Kiran. Thanks for answering. Are you running on a TV? Does it work in the emulator as well? The deeplink itself works, but the app is reloaded every time. I've read in the docs that this "reload" property is for mobile and wearable only. Do you confirm your app opens the link without a reload?

Comment: I have checked on a 2018 TV and it works fine. This documentation is for Smart TV specifically and reload property is mentioned: https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/guides/smart-hub-preview/implementing-personal-preview.html. My app does not reload.

Comment: Hi Kiran. Thanks for your answer. It happens that the app always reload in the emulator. It is working fine when running on a real device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably modyfing window.location in the app (ie in router).

reload='disable' prevents reloading index.html. When application receives app control request and page is different, application will be reloaded.

You can find more about appcontrol in Tizen documentation (note that Tizen for TV may differ from other devices):
https://docs.tizen.org/application/web/guides/app-management/app-controls/

Comment: Hi, @winGuETA, thanks for your response. I am modifying location.hash. But even if I'm not, the appcontrol event is never triggered.

Comment: You can check the official sample: https://github.com/SamsungDForum/SampleWebApps-PublicPreview/blob/master/js/main.js

Accoring to your description implementation seems correct; App must be added to home, the event should be triggered when you choose another tile from preview when app is already started.

Comment: So, it happens that this 'appcontrol' event is only available in the actual TV. It does not work in the emulator. I did not have access to a real TV at that moment, but I could just try it on one now and it worked. Thanks @winGuETA

Answer (score 0):

I've got some information regarding your question.

To do application resume without Page reload,
Set extra data in app-control like below

- key: SkipReload
- value: Yes

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but that data is not recognized by TizenStudio at all. It can't compile if I add it. Anyways, the issue only happens in the emulator, so I guess it will always reload the app there.